# I am unable to show any message after successful validation In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am unable to show any message after successful validation in JavaScript, and I am going wrong in the end if Statement. I want to display we will get back to you after it passes validation.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x.length < 10) {
        window.alert("The field cannot contain more than 10 characters!");
        return false;
    }
}
function validateForm() {
    var k = document.forms["myForm"]["query"].value;
    if (k.length < 25) {
        window.alert("The field cannot contain atleast 25 characters!");
        return false;
    }
}
function validateForm() {
    var k1 = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = k1.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = k1.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= k1.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    if (k1.length < 10) {
        window.alert("The field cannot contain atleast 25 characters!");
    }
}
if (x && k && k1 !== true) {
    this.x = x;
    this.k = k;
    this.k1 = k1;
    window.alert("We will get back to you");
}
</script>
```

Comment: you have 3 functions with the same name.. how do you expect it to work? do you call this validateForm function anywhere?

Comment: I tried to pt it in the same function but it validated only fname. It never went to next variable say var k

Comment: Can you please fix it ?

Comment: That's because you are returning false after each validation.. you should return only at the end of function.. you should keep only one function and call it when submitting the form

Comment: Post your html form code as well in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x.length < 10){
     window.alert("The field cannot contain more than 10 characters!");
     isValid = false;
  }

  var k = document.forms["myForm"]["query"].value;
  if (k.length<25) {
     window.alert("The field cannot contain atleast 25 characters!");
     isValid = false;
  }

  var k1= document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var atpos = k1.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = k1.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= k1.length) {
     alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
     isValid = false;
  }
  if (k1.length < 10) {
     window.alert("The field cannot contain atleast 25 characters!");
     isValid = false;
  }
  if (!isValid) {
     // you should take a look here.. what do you want to achieve?
     this.x = x;
     this.k = k;
     this.k1 = k1;
     window.alert("We will get back to you");
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

your form should use the `onsubmit` attribute:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()"></form>
```

Take a look at http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ . You may consider starting to learn [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or another js framework.